# Coded UI codeduiswitchfromimmersive.exe crashes

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests

I'm hoping that someone can help me I'm working on some Coded UI tests and when I try to play them back they run though but I get the below when they are finished.

[image: CodedUITestSwitchFromImmersive.exe error window]

Is there anything I am missing or do you have any ideas.
I get this from both recorded and hand written tests.
I'm using Visual Studio 2015 enterprise.

Answer (score -1):

I have never seen anything like this, but you can allwais try to:

1. Reboot VS and try to run the test again
2. Reboot the PC and try to run the test agin
3. Make sure you are running VS in administrator mode

If the problem is still there then check the event viewer on the PC where you are running the test:

- Right Click My Computer - Manage - Event Viewer - Windows Logs - Application

It is possible that you have some more information regarding that error there!

Comment: Debugging hints go in comments, not in answers.